# WPF MVVM Light - About views communicating

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am currently working on a project for work.  I am seeking an outside design opinion, as well as some general information on the issue I am faced with.

We have a MainWindow.xaml file that is located in the root directory of the project.  In this main window is some design and logic for some collapsing stack panels, ribbon toolbar, etc.

So far the idea is to include a different  in each stack panel to help make the code neat.  The views are located in a 'Views' folder.  So just to be clear, the MainWindow.xaml and other views ARE NOT in the same directory.  This is open to change, if necessary.

So here is my question/issue:  We have a Window ('A'), a main panel with a collapsable stack panel with some information ('B') that is contained in window 'A'.  Then there is another stack panel to manage the contents in 'B', (collapse/visisble) ('C').

'A' contains a toggle button to show/collapse 'B'.
'B' contains a button to show/collapse 'C'.
'C' contains a button to show/collapse itself, 'C'.

'C' *should* have its logic all contain within a view, so the MainWindow ('A') should have a simple tag:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource FrameGradient}"  Tag="{Binding ElementName=ToggleButton}">
    <view:Content></view:Content>
</StackPanel>
```

Currently, the bindings for toggling the buttons within 'A' are in the styling.  The In this case FrameGradient has triggers like so:

```
<Style x:Key="FrameGradient" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    //Setter properties
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Is it possible to, within the 'Content' View to TOGGLE the panel, 'C', which is NOT within the view?  I feel like I am missing a core idea of XAML here.  I found a 'cheap' work around which is to place the 'Close' button from the Content View outside of the  tags, but then that leads to styling issues and I feel like I shouldn't have to do something silly like that.  Again, the idea is that the toggle button for Stack Panel 'C' is contained within another view and I want to be able to toggle it from another view.

I apologize if I am not clear enough, I will provide whoever asks with more information if required here.

**UPDATE**
I have some time to actually add the code I am using so that this might make more sense.

MainWindow.xaml - Logic for Filter panel (Located in root)

```
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource FrameGradient}">
        <Grid x:Name="FilterContentGrid">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <view:Filters></view:Filters>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Filters.xaml - Logic for Filters view (Located in /Views)
The button within the file that needs to Collapse the above StackPanel.

```
<Button x:Name="FilterManagementCloseButton" Content="CLOSE"></Button>
```

Theme.Xaml - Logic for all styling (Located in root, along with MainWindow.xaml and App.xaml)
Button Styling

```
<Style x:Key="FilterManagementCloseButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,5,20,3" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Local:MainWindow}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

And finally, the FrameGradient Styling also located in Theme.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="FrameGradient" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Tag.IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

SO, I hope this makes things more clear.  I want the CLOSE button within Filters.xaml to COLLAPSE the stackpanel that is located in MainWindow.  I realize this code is a mess at the moment.

Comment: I would assume creating a `MainWindowViewModel` class that implements INPC would help. Adding `bool` properties like `IsBVisible and `IsCVisible`, maybe with logic in the `get`ters sounds applicable.  Then, set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` to an instance of your `MainWindowViewModel` and you can bind by doing something like `<StackPanel IsVisible="{Binding IsBVisible, Converter={StaticResource VisConverter}}" />`, assuming you have '<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="VisConverter />` in your Resources.

Comment: In my particular case I have a MainWindowVM but I also have a FiltersVM (the panel I am trying to show).  Each panel within the main window has it's own VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to, within the 'Content' View to TOGGLE the panel, 'C',
>   which is NOT within the view?

Create a shared VM which each other VM will have a property for which it can access. This VM can be loaded with during initialization of the other VMs. To allow for changes to happen put INotifyProperty(ies) on the shared VM which will then flag the desired logic across all views. Finally bind the target control(s) to your datacontext as normal except sub path into the shared VM target's property.

Hence when one view toggles (two way binding) a shared property it is reflected on the view of the target panel.

#### Update Example

The idea here is that one creates a viewmodel for the AppPage. That VM will hold generic flags which are shared across all viewmodels. Each subsequently created ViewModel will have a reference to the AppPage's viewmodel.

The example below is a mainpage where the `AppVM` contains a flag which informs the mainpage whether a login is in process. If it is and that value is `true` then a bound button on the mainpage will be enabled.

[image]

Subsequently the mainpage can override the appvm and put a new value within that flag by a bounded checkbox that can *in-directly* change whether the button is enabled; thus changing the flag for all other VMs in the process.

Here is the Mainpage VM, for this example I simply create the AppVM, but it could be passed in, or gotten from a static reference elsewhere. NOTE also how I don't care when `AV`s (appVM) property changes; it is not required for this example (we are not binding anything to AppVM, just its properties which need to be monitored).

```
public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public AppVM AV { get; set; }

     public MainVM()
     {
        AV = new AppVM() { LoginInProcess = true };
     }
}
```

Here is the AppVm

```
   public class AppVM : INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private bool _LoginInProcess;

        public bool LoginInProcess
        {
            get {  return _LoginInProcess; }
            set { _LoginInProcess = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
}
```

Here is MainPage's Xaml where the datacontext has been set to an instance of `MainVM`:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <CheckBox Content="Override"
              IsChecked="{Binding AV.LoginInProcess, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    <Button Content="Login"
            IsEnabled="{Binding AV.LoginInProcess}"
            Width="75" />

</StackPanel>
```

I base the MVVM off of my blog article [Xaml: ViewModel Main Page Instantiation and Loading Strategy for Easier Binding](http://omegacoder.com/?p=1017) which explains the other missing items of this example such as the mainpage's datacontext loading.

Comment: Do you have a code example by chance?  It seems like you want to create a way to relate view models to other view models... Doesn't this violate the idea of the MvvM framework?

Comment: @user1296981 As long as one's data exists on something that is not a `model` or not a `view` that is the MVVM concept. Having a `ViewModel` with a property which is simply a reference to another `VM` is basically a hierarchy of data; nothing more nothing less.

Comment: I'm having some issues with those since the control I need to hide/show is not in the Main Window, but the toggle button to handle it IS located in the MainWindow.xaml..  I can't seem to bind the visibility to the AV.IsVisible property I made from the other view, since they are not using the same VM.

Comment: @user1296981 Does the other VM you mentioned have an AV property?

Comment: I added an AppVM property to both my MainWindowVm and my FilterVM.

Comment: Declared: public ApplicationVM AV { get; set; }

Comment: Construcotr for both VMs: AV = new ApplicationVM() { IsFilterToolBarVisible = false };

Comment: so toggling the button should switch it to true, and then i put a booltovis converted on the visibility of the dockpanel that i want to show, which is located in the other view (which has the view model with the 2nd declaration of AV)

Comment: Also, something else is strange..  When I toggle the variable in the construct in a VM, doesn't matter which of the 2, from false to true it shows in the designer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57454/discussion-between-user1296981-and-omegaman).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`RelativeSource Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx)s to bind from child views to properties in parent view models. Let's say you have a `ToggleButton` in `MainWindow.xaml` that is data bound to a property named `IsChecked`, which is declared in the object that is data bound to the `MainWindow DataContext` property. You could data bind to that same property from any child view with a `RelativeSource Binding`, like this:

```
<Style x:Key="FrameGradient" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
    <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsChecked, RelativeSource={
            RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Local:MainWindow}}}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="StackPanel.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <!-- Note that there is no need for two Triggers here -->
        <!-- One Setter and one Trigger is enough -->
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Are you writing this based on the assumption that the <style> tag is contained within the MainWindow?  All of my styles are in a Theme.xaml file that is also contained in the root directory.  I forgot to mention that part, I apologize.

Comment: A `RelativeSource Binding` is a `RelativeSource Binding` wherever it is declared.

Comment: I'm still having issues trying to get this to work.  The binding for Path=DataContext.IsChecked isn't making much sense to me.  I was under the impression IsChecked works only with toggle buttons, checkboxes etc.  I want to bind the action to collapse the panel to a regular button, unless there is a better way.  Also, For some reason the UserControl for the Filters with the stack panel collapse button can NOT see my Theme.xaml file, even though it is configured in the App.xaml as an Application resource.

Comment: Read my answer again. *a `ToggleButton` in `MainWindow.xaml` that is data bound to a property named `IsChecked`, **which is declared in the object that is data bound to the `MainWindow DataContext` property***.